# Executing function once in a game loop

Tags: javascript

I have a game loop that refreshes ~20 times per second with the following condition, inside function growPlayerBlockCounterWinner():

```
if (obstacleArray[i][2] > canvas.height) {player.size += 5;}
```

That means: if black object goes outside the canvas area, player size will increase by 5 pixels.

The function normally executes once, but due to putting it in a game loop, it executes each time the game is refreshed, so player is growing continuously.

Previously i had it with the sign '=' instead od '>', but that was working well when black blocks were moving pixel by pixel and i want them to move faster.

You can inspect the problem and full code on the remote server: https://stacho163.000webhostapp.com/firstLevel.html

Below I paste only my obstacle functions:

```
// js game script //

let obstacle = {
    size: 0,
    posX: 0,
    posY: 0,
    speed: 0
}

let obstacleArray = new Array(100);

function generateObstacle() {
    for (i = 0; i < obstacleArray.length; i++) {
        obstacle.size = Math.round((Math.random() * 100) + 50);
        obstacle.posX = Math.round((Math.random() * (canvas.width - 
obstacle.size)));
        obstacle.posY = -450 - (i * 100);
        obstacle.speed = 5;
        obstacleArray[i] = [obstacle.size, obstacle.posX, obstacle.posY, 
obstacle.speed];
    }
}

function drawObstacle() {
    for (i = 0; i < obstacleArray.length; i++) {
        ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
        ctx.fillRect(obstacleArray[i][1], obstacleArray[i][2], 
obstacleArray[i][0], obstacleArray[i][0]);
        obstacleArray[i][2] += obstacleArray[i][3];
    }
}

function growPlayerBlockCounterWinner() {
    for (i = 0; i < obstacleArray.length; i++) {
        // grow player
        if (obstacleArray[i][2] > canvas.height) {
            player.size += 5;         
        }     
    }
}

generateObstacle();

function game() {
    drawObstacle();
    growPlayerBlockCounterWinner();
    requestAnimationFrame(game);
}

requestAnimationFrame(game);
```

I am looking for opinions, maybe my logic about that statement is incorrect or i should place that statement in other place.

Thanks for your tips :)

Comment: Maybe you could remove an obstacle, once it is out of view. Something like `if (obstacleArray[i][2] > canvas.height) {
            player.size += 5;   
            obstacleArray.splice(i, 1);
        }  `

Comment: Thanks for dropping an idea. I did an update on the remote server, but it causes the next black box flashing when the previous is removed (also problems with moving green blocks). I think it occurs because the if statement is still checking the statement, till the next block come. Now it looks sth like if(sth empty > canvas.height), that can't be even compared, so it produces an error. Just my idea.

Comment: Ok, I see the problem. Another idea: as you have a defined number of black boxes, you might be able to store, for which black box the player already increased size like this: `var affectedBlackBoxes = {}; // ... // if (obstacleArray[i][2] > canvas.height && !affectedBlackBoxes[i]) {
            player.size += 5; affectedBlackBoxes[i] = true;         
        }  `

Comment: Updated with your idea. I've done it ealier with boolean. Before if, boolean was set to false and at the end of if statement i did changed it to true. Is that the same approach? Anyway it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: I am sorry, my answer was not clear. The definition of `var affectedBlackBoxes = {};` must not be in the function; this way it gets reinitialized every frame. You have to declare it next to `let player = {}; `

Comment: indeed it's working correctly. Thank you for your efforts. Post it as answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I am glad to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have a defined number of black boxes, you might be able to store, for which black box the player already increased size like this:

```
let obstacle = {...};
var affectedBlackBoxes = {};

//...//

function growPlayerBlockCounterWinner() {
  for (i = 0; i < obstacleArray.length; i++) {
    // grow player
    if (obstacleArray[i][2] > canvas.height && !affectedBlackBoxes[i]) {
      player.size += 5;     
      affectedBlackBoxes[i] = true;    
    }     
  }
}
```